# wifi only when traveling; also necessary to turn off packet data?

Tags: wi-fi, data-monitoring

My son has a Galaxy S3 and is travelling to Russia. He'd like to be able to use his phone for Internet use, and Skype, when connected to Wifi. Otherwise, he doesn't want to incur extra or roaming charges for voice, text, or data.

I thought I had this figured out. The instructions I got were to

1) go into airplane mode, and then

2) turn Wifi back on.

However, I just called ATT, to verify my approach, and the person said he also has to go to

3) Applications -> Settings>  -> More Settings -> Wireless and Network -> Mobile Network -> Use PacketS Data

and uncheck "Use Packet Data"

I Step 3 necessary, even after having done Step 1 and Step 2?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On android devices, when you turn airplane mode on, it automatically disables Packets Data usage and any other network functionality.

After, you can turn wifi on without any extra cost issue.